# PECL installed gnupg calls return null

Tags: php, mamp, gnupg, pecl

I recently installed gnupg using PECL to my MAMP PHP install.

```
extension_loaded('gnupg'); // returns true
```

My PHP code is able to recognized the gnupg calls, but every call I make seems to return null, as if nothing is happening on the back end.

I'm able to create a new gnupg() object and call import on that object, but this returns null.  According to the documentation, it should return FALSE on failure.

```
$gpg = new gnupg();
$key = "-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK----- ..."; //truncated for posting on SO
$info = $gpg->import($key); // returns null
```

I have also tried to run export() using the example code in the documentation as a sanity check, but received the same null result.

The PECL install process results in the following:

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.7/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/gnupg.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/gnupg-1.3.6
```

I see gnupg.so but I do not see a gnupg.a file.  Nearly all the other .so files in that folder have a related .a file, could that file be missing and that's why I'm getting strange results?

Has anyone run into this before?

EDIT:

Referenced documentation: 
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.gnupg.php

Comment: Is `var_dump($gpg)` printing anything reasonabel?

Comment: var_dump($gpg) output:  
    object(gnupg)#40 (0) {
    }

Comment: This is the expected output (I have the same on my Linux box with working GnuPG in PHP), so at least the object seemed to be initialized correctly. Have you set `error_reporting(E_ALL);`? If this does not return anything important, I'm out of ideas. Has the user the web server is running under a home directory set? But I'd expect PHP to print a reasonable error message if there would be a problem like this...

Comment: I set error_reporting(E_ALL); and there was no change in either the apache or php error log.  Should I be concerned about there being no gnupg.a file?

Comment: `error_reporting` influences the output that is printed, not the log files. I'm sorry, I'm out of ideas what's going wrong.

Comment: I've determined that the calls aren't returning null, but are all failing.  There is minimal error messaging in gnupg; do you have any resources on trouble shooting 'import failed' issues?